# How do I get the perforce root directory from command line?

Tags: perforce

How do I get the perforce root directory from the command line? I've tried `p4 info` but I'd rather not have to filter this to get at the root. I'm sure there's a way, but I couldn't find it.

Is there a way to get the root in a context sensitive way? For example if I have two workspaces with a hierarchy like A/.../script vs B/.../script I'd expect that the script would return either A or B depending on where it was run from.

Comment: What exactly is the “perforce root directory” here? The Root attribute of the client (which may or may not exist on your current machine, since it may use an AltRoot, e.g., for cross-platform clients)?

Comment: I think @ChristopherCreutzig is correct here. The `p4 info` is going to resolve to your current settings, whereas grabbing it from the workspace is going to require simulating what Perforce does to handle AltRoot...

Comment: Is there a way to grab it from p4 info without filtering? For example p4 info root?

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem with `p4 info | grep 'Client root:' | cut -d ' ' -f 3-` is that you're trying to avoid. But I never checked if, e.g., `p4 info` is localized – and if not, that might change in the future.

Comment: using grep seems like kind of a hack, especially on windows

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  What do you mean by "How do I get the perforce root directory"?  Are we talking root on the server install of the box or the root (head) revision of a file?

Comment: Let's say I have a hierarchy like //depot/A/B/C
I want to write a script that will find C with an absolute path by determining //depot on the client's machine - this way I can do operations in a client mapping ignostic way without using relative paths

Comment: Then it sounds like you want 'p4 where //depot/A/B/C'.

Comment: @BryanPendleton Please promote your comment into an answer. I think a significant portion of readers of this question actually want this. Also link to [manual for `p4 where`](https://www.perforce.com/manuals/v16.2/cmdref/p4_where.html) would be helpful.

Answer (score 17):

If you want your client root in one command run:

```
p4 -F %clientRoot% -ztag info
```

You will need the 2014.1 later version of p4 to use this flag.

Comment: It works for me. You may have older version of the P4 client some1.

Comment: You're correct Tor. I've updated the answer to clarify.

Comment: This breaks if 'clientRoot' is already set in the environment. Escape the second percent sign: `%clientRoot^%`. But because CMD is *special* that only works if you type it yourself at a prompt. To do it in a batch file you have to say `%%clientRoot^^^%%`, which is pretty hideous.

Comment: This works pretty fine but out of curiosity, do you know how the %clientRoot% variable is set? I tested this with 2 different roots that both have P4CLIENT set in a P4CONFIG.txt file so probably clientRoot is set through P4CLIENT?

Comment: @Matt ...also, what's that -ztag parameter for?

Comment: The -ztag tells p4 to dump out the dictionary of values sent back from the server. For a lot of commands the server sends back more info than the client uses when formatting the message

Answer (score 1):

For older versions before 2014.1 use the command

> p4 info | grep 'Client root:' | cut -d ' ' -f 3-

Answer (score 1):

From OP’s description, they probably want [`p4 where`](https://www.perforce.com/manuals/v16.2/cmdref/p4_where.html). For example, if the client root is `/perforce/projects`, then

```
p4 where //depot/project-1/module-2
```

will give `/perforce/projects/project-1/module-2`. Credit from [Bryan’s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21809199/how-do-i-get-the-perforce-root-directory-from-command-line#comment33060351_21809199).